# react-google-maps toggle Heatmap visibility

Tags: javascript

I have a google map setup using [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) and I am using the [heatmap component](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#heatmaplayer) to display a heatmap overlaid ontop of the map. This works well on initial load, but I'm having some difficulty toggling the visibility of the heatmap.

In the example found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap they have access to a `heatmap` variable to do things like `heatmap.setMap()` and `heatmap.getMap()`.

From what I can tell, using `react-google-maps` doesn't provide a method for accessing the instance of the map or heatmap.

So how does one go about toggling the heatmap on/off?

```
import HeatmapLayer from "react-google-maps/lib/visualization/HeatmapLayer";

const MapaPerfilW = withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={15}
        position={{ lat: 37.782551, lng: -122.445368 }}
    >
        <HeatmapLayer
            data={[
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
                new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461)
            ]}
        />
    </GoogleMap>
));
```

Component Code:
https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/lib/components/visualization/HeatmapLayer.js

Answer (score 0):

Rather than turn visibility on and off, you have to make its presence depend on a property or state and when it changes, the heatmap will be rendered or not accordingly.

Comment: How exactly is this done? If I use useState and send null or and empty array or check conditionally the old heatmap will persist on the map even, if the checks are false or it doesnt receive data.